# Is there any function in which the Maclaurin series evaluates to having prime numbered powers and factorials?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, prime-numbers, taylor-expansion

I am searching for any information or analysis regarding the functions
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p\left(n\right)}}{\left(p\left(n\right)\right)!}$$
or
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{p\left(n\right)}}{\left(p\left(n\right)\right)!}$$
Where $p(n)$ is the nth prime number.

In particular, are there any expressions that are equal to either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ ?

And on a related note, is there any function $k(x)$ in which the $n$th derivative at $0$, $k^n(0)$ gives the nth prime number?

Thank you all.

Comment: There is some information here: https://oeis.org/A100124